# Strange text output when booting

Tags: boot, grub2

In the last few days I've got strange warnings(?) when booting. Furthermore sometimes my notebook doesn't even start ubuntu or grub, then it simply shuts down or UEFI gives me the possibility to boot windows. I think the reason for this might be my hard disk although its just a few months old. The bugs are often quite different and I am not able to understand them. 
Dmesg output: http://pastebin.com/FFFRJPVS

I think this might be the interesting part: http://pastebin.com/pRrHUZQT

Do you think my hardware is damaged?

Answer (score 1):

It certainly looks like a hardware problem, but not necessarily a damaged disk. Turn your notebook upside down, unscrew the lid of the disk compartment and see if the disk is pressed firmly against the connector. This may help. And do make backups.